# Merge identical parts of two strings in tcl

Tags: string, tcl, string-comparison

I have two strings

```
str1 "Something, part of"
```

and

```
str2 "Something"
```

Out of These I would like to filter out the part which is identical in both strings, in this case the substring "Something"

Is there a string function which can accomplish this? I really want to avoid looping through the whole string using foreach.

Comment: Will the identical part always be in the beginning of both strings? In that case, try textutil::longestCommonPrefix.

Comment: Yes, the identical part will always be in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a common prefix in some strings, use `::textutil::string::longestCommonPrefix`:

```
% package require textutil::string
0.7.1
% ::textutil::string::longestCommonPrefix "Something, part of" Something
Something
% ::textutil::string::longestCommonPrefix "Something, part of" Somethang
Someth
```

There is also a `::textutil::string::longestCommonPrefixList` that takes a list of strings as argument.

Note that using the `textutil` bundle as I did in my comment is deprecated. Sorry.

Documentation:
[textutil::string (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_string.html)